# PYQT5 Signals & Slots are not working even though i followed the documentation

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to send signal and receive it between two windows, i followed exactly the documentation.

While running the program : No error Nor receiving the signal in the slot

While Debugging in @pycharm: i receive below error :

```
TypeError: connect() failed between started() and _signal()
```

Two files Codes are below:

First file name: Signals.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
import slots

class aaa(qtw.QWidget,qtc.QObject):
    submitted = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        self.edit = qtw.QLineEdit()
        self.submit=qtw.QPushButton('Submit',clicked=self.onSubmit)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.edit)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.submit)
        self.show()

    def onSubmit(self):
        self.submitted.emit(self.edit.text())
        self.close()
        self.myDialog2 = slots.bbb()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = aaa()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Second file name: slots.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
import Signals

class bbb(qtw.QWidget,qtc.QThread):

    @qtc.pyqtSlot()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        self.label = qtw.QLabel(self)


        self.x=Signals.aaa()
        self.x.submitted.connect(self.label.setText)
        print(self.label.text())

        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)
        self.show()
```

Comment: Looks like a pycharm bug. If you run it outside of pycharm it will probably work fine. When using an IDE, always test your script in a standard console before assuming there's a problem with your code.

Comment: thank you ekhumoro. sure i will

Comment: @ekhumoro if i want to use this method on switch between screens forward and back it wont work, i made separate post for it, can you explain what is the problem in it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62786340/open-new-window-and-close-current-window-and-going-back-if-both-windows-codes-ge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>I do not know what documentation refers to the OP so I could not indicate if the tutorial you are following is correct or not. If you are referring to the official docs then you clearly have not followed it correctly.</sub>

Your code has many errors so I will only mention the most important ones:

- The connection must be used before emitting the signal,
- You should not inherit from QObject and QWidget since they will have conflicts, in addition to that there is no justification.
- You shouldn't use pyqtSlot unnecessarily, setting it in the contstructor doesn't make sense.
- You are creating a circular import.
- "self.x" is not "mw" but another object.

A possible solution is the following:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc


class bbb(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lay = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = qtw.QLabel()
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
```

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
import slots


class aaa(qtw.QWidget, qtc.QObject):
    submitted = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.edit = qtw.QLineEdit()
        self.submit = qtw.QPushButton("Submit", clicked=self.onSubmit)
        lay = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.edit)
        lay.addWidget(self.submit)
        
        self.myDialog2 = slots.bbb()
        self.submitted.connect(self.myDialog2.label.setText)

    def onSubmit(self):
        self.submitted.emit(self.edit.text())
        self.close()

        self.myDialog2.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = aaa()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... That was fast & precise.... all your comments are valid... i just needed to add this line to your code to make it run .... self.setLayout(lay)